# In Erlang, can I use ets:tab2list without including line breaks for nested tuples?

Tags: file-io, erlang, ets

I am creating an ets;

```
ets:new(myets,[duplicate_bag,public,named_table]).
```

I am putting in data in the following formats:

```
{120869,message,item1,item2,status1,success}
{120869,message,item1,item2,status1,fail}
{120869,action,message,{oldsetting,40},{newsetting,50}}
{93195,model_status}
```

I would like to save each of these as a separate line in a text file. I am attempting this in the following way:

```
Data = ets:tab2list(myets)
```

This gives:

```
[{120869,message,item1,item2,status1,success},
{120869,message,item1,item2,status1,fail},
{120869,action,message,
 {oldsetting,40},
 {newsetting,50}},
{93195,model_status}]
```

I then use `io:format` to save to file.

However, I wonder if there is a simple way to save `myets` to a text file without putting a line breaks in the third tuple (with the nested tuples beginning `oldsetting` and `newsetting`)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a simple printing function should do the trick:

```
print_list(List, File) ->
   lists:foreach(fun(X) -> io:write(File, X), io:nl(File) end, List).
```

However, if you just want to save the ets table you can use `to_dets/2` (and open it with `from_dets/2`).

Answer (score 1):

If you have file device in File, then just execute:

```
[io:format(File, "~p\n", [I]) || I <- Data].
```

But if you want to store really big tables, this way is not memory efficient.

And why do you want to store this data? Maybe it is better just to use dets?